# Could I mine on Ethereum without storing any of the blockchain?

Tags: mining, storage, proof-of-work

If a reference node provides an API so that I can read from their copy of the blockchain, could I run Ethash, do proof-of-work and claim rewards while not storing anything?

Comment: Just use a mining pool if you don't want to download the blockchain. You can find them by searching by their name - see https://etherscan.io/stat/miner?range=7&blocktype=blocks .

Answer (score 1):

No. you have to pull complete data of blockchain before start mining.
You should have it locally, if mining on PC, or on any server, if mining there.